# How set 2 environment (PATH and proxy_env ) in ansible-playbook?

Tags: ansible

How correct write task ?

```
- name: Install required python modules
  pip:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    extra_args: "{{ pip_extra_args | default(omit) }}"
  with_items: "{{pip_python_coreos_modules}}"
  environment:
    PATH: "some path"
  environment: "{{ proxy_env }}"
```

How set 2 environment (PATH and proxy_env ) ?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you already know how to set one environment variable. Just add another key to that dictionary (`proxy_env: "some value"` right after the line that sets the `PATH` variable).

Answer (score 0):

Ansible makes it easy for you to configure your environment by using the ‘environment’ keyword. Here is an example:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - apt: name=cobbler state=installed
    environment:
       http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

The environment can also be stored in a variable, and accessed like so:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  # here we make a variable named "proxy_env" that is a dictionary
  vars:
    proxy_env:
       http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080
  tasks:
  - apt: name=cobbler state=installed
    environment: "{{proxy_env}}"
```

Whole thing in explained in ansible docs, you can read it [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html)

Comment: https://github.com/patsevanton/kubespray/blob/master/roles/bootstrap-os/tasks/bootstrap-coreos.yml#L70

Code can contain only variable